# App Engine Python Authentication Custom Redirect

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, authentication, python-2.7

```
handlers:
- url: /secure_api/.*
  script: _go_app
  login: required
  auth_fail_action: unauthorized
```

This code only brings me to a page saying "Login required to view page."  Is there a way to instead redirect to my home page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `auth_fail_action: unauthorized`, you get the page you are seeing (see [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status) for the details). Changing `unauthorized` to `redirect` will take them to the login screen, but if you want to do more granular handling of users based on their logged-in status, your best bet is to do it inside of your code via the `Users` API. For instance (this is adapted from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/)), here is a simple example that would redirect a non-logged-in user to `/`:

```
from google.appengine.api import users
import webapp2

class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            # Do stuff here for logged-in users
        else:
            # Redirect if user is None, which is the case for non-logged-in users
            self.redirect('/')
```